# libGDX gwt missing gwt-module

Tags: java, gwt, error-handling, module, libgdx

I have a problem with running a GWT html application. Any suggestion?

first error:

```
Referenced file contains errors (http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd).  For more information, right click on the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details..."
```

Second error:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Referenced file contains errors (http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd).  For more information, right click on the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details..." GdxDefinitionSuperdev.gwt.xml   /Dendron3Dv2-html/src/psyrot/td/dendron3d   line 1  XML Problem
```

Sdk and Gwt designer etc.. is already installed. And I am gwt-2.7.0 version.